# Unable to connect to websites which donot start with www

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I have created hotspot from my Andriod mobile and using Internet on laptop Windows 7 but I'm unable to connect to websites which don't start with `www.`.

The error:

> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web

**Should the settings be done on mobile or laptop? What should I change?**

Note I am using mobile data. Websites starting with `www.` are working fine. The problem doesn't occur on my phone. Also everything is OK when my laptop uses LAN.

Mobile(alone with data) and laptop(alone with LAN) works fine , it is only when mobile hotspot is used in laptop, i am not able to access websites which don't start with www.

Comment: Check the Firefox setting in the about:config for browser.fixup.alternate.prefix. It's default is 'www.' (uncluding the period), unless changed.

Comment: @wbogacz can please suggest any link how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I prevent Firefox to use: www.foo.bar instead of foo.bar?](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Firefox-for-Android/How-do-I-prevent-Firefox-to-use-www-foo-bar-instead-of-foo-bar/m-p/790424#M19751) suggests setting `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled to disabled` to be a working solution

**Steps Involved** [Source](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Learn-the-Basics-get-started/Search-the-web-from-the-address-bar/ta-p/645)

- Turning off Domain Guessing

  - In the address bar, type `about:config` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - The `about:config` "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise! to continue to the `about:config page`. (There's no warranty with Mozilla so I suppose this is to just a warning joke)
  - In the Search field, type `fixup`.Double-click the `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` preference to set its value to false.
- Changing the prefix (to `www` )

  - In the `about:config page`, double-click the `browser.fixup.alternate.prefix`
  - In the pop up menu enter `www.`  ( if that doesn't help try `www` without `.` )

This is perhaps what was suggested in [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/10913/wbogacz)

Comment: ok will try , but one thing websites without www. is working with other LAN network on my laptop , it does not work only when connected to mobile data hotspot , so i was thinking settings should be done on mobile ,also please note that websites works on my mobile.

Comment: will check today , was using proxy websites..

Answer (score 0):

> 1)Go Wireless Network connections Status.
>
> 2)Properties
>
> 3)Networking
>
> 4)Configure

After doing this there was error DHCP not there , I gave auto fix in windows.
And all websites started working.